# Change dynamically component of View

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I am trying make a ticket system with asp core, and the point where I get stuck is; i need to change a part of view when click a link in view. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reacting to a click event that means you will be manipulating the already rendered HTML document in the browser. You can use multiple ways of manipulating the DOM. Plain javascript, or some framework, such as JQuery or Angular.

This is an example of reacting to the click event in javascript:

```
<div id='partOfView'>
    Some text.
<div>

<button onclick="buttonClicked()">Click me!</button>

<script>
    function buttonClicked() {
        var el = document.getElementById('partOfView');
        el.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
</script>
```